# SVG/D3 Group Flashes Once and then Transition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I have a group created as follows:

```
 d3.select("#" + chartId).selectAll("g.barChart")
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("id", chartId)
        .attr("style", "opacity:0");
```

Further down the code, I have this so the group will fade in:

```
graph = d3.select(".bar#"+chartId);
graph.transition().delay(300).duration(2000).attr("style", "opacity:1.0");
```

I can't figure out why the groups will flash once or more before it fades in.  When I commented out the above transition line, the groups stay invisible.  That should mean nothing else is causing the flash.  I'm stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying transitions over `style` D3 attempts to interpolate the values from a string, and something might be going wrong. Try transitioning opacity as an attribute instead of including it in `style`:

```
 d3.select("#" + chartId).selectAll("g.barChart")
    .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("id", chartId)
        .attr("opacity", "0");

graph = d3.select(".bar#"+chartId);
graph.transition().delay(300).duration(2000).attr("opacity", "1");
```

Comment: It would probably also be an option to instead of `.attr("opacity", "1.0")` use `.style("opacity", "1.0")` and to transition the style instead of the attr, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-style.